# I closed "sharepoint-lists" in outlook. How do I reopen this item?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, sharepoint-2013

In the folder tree on the left frame of my outlook window there was an entry called "Sharepoint-Lists" containing a tree of all connected sharepoint lists.

I selected "close Sharepoint-Lists" and they all disappeared from my folder tree. The lists are still connected to outlook but i can't navigate there any longer.

How can I make them reappear in the folder tree?

Comment: Can you go to actions and connect to Outlook and see if they reappear.

Comment: The folder opens but does not appear in the tree.

Comment: Have you tried to re-connect a list from inside SharePoint?  If not - try that and see if re-enables the tree view.

Comment: @JesusShelby This didn't work until a recent change done by our IT dept. I do not know, what they changed, but somehow your solution seems to work now. Thanks!